# How to install Horde Webmail on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, github, horde

Am using Ubuntu 14.04. Am stuck with the following issue:

My goal is to install and have running **HORDER GROUPWARE 5.2** on my Domain/Hosting:

Download on Github: 
  https:// github .com/horde/horde/releases/tag/groupware-5.2.2

Installation on Github: 
 https://github.com/horde/horde/tree/master/bundles/groupware

Demo: 
 http://demo.horde.org/

> Quick Install
>
> > These are very terse instructions how to install Horde Groupware and
> >     its prerequisites on a LAMP sytem. They are addressed to experienced
> >     administrators who know exactly what they are doing.  For more
> >     detailed instructions, start reading below at Prerequisites_.
>
> 1. Compiling PHP for Apache 2::
>
>    cd php-x.x.x/
>       ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs2 \
>                   --with-gettext --enable-mbstring=all --enable-mbregex \
>                   --with-gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
>                   [--with-mysql|--with-pgsql|--with-oci8]
>                   [--with-tidy]
>                   [--with-ftp]
>       make
>       make install

Can't even start with this method couse there is not such "php-x.x.x" folder on my ubuntu root, and there is not such think on internet called "compiling php for apache2". Any idea?

> 2. Restart Apache.
> 3. Register Horde PEAR channel::
>
>    pear channel-discover pear.horde.org
> 4. Set Horde installation directory::
>
>    pear install horde/horde_role
>       pear run-scripts horde/horde_role
> 5. Install Horde Groupware::
>
>    pear install -a -B horde/groupware
> 6. Run installation script::
>
>    groupware-install
> 7. Test Horde Groupware::
>
>    http:// your-server /horde/test.php

So I try to install it with the other way that is explained on the INSTALLATION guide:

> Prerequisites
>
> The following prerequisites are **REQUIRED** for Horde Groupware to
>   function properly.
>
> 1. A webserver that supports PHP.
>
>    Horde Groupware is primarily developed under the Apache and
>      Lighttpd    webservers, which we recommend.  These servers are
>      available from:
>
>    http:// httpd.apache .org/
>        http:// www.lighttpd .net/

(MY NOTE: i use Apache 2 I have LAMP already installed and functioning well on my OS)
 OK! Done,

> 2. A web server with PATH_INFO support.
>
>    The dynamic interfaces of Horde Groupware requires a web server
>      that    correctly sets the PATH_INFO environment variable for all PHP
>      scripts. Every    modern web server supports this, but you might have
>      to enable this feature    in the web server configuration.  e.g.
>      Apache servers require::
>
>    AcceptPathInfo On
>
>    Lighttpd servers require::
>
>    "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"

Can't continue from this point couse I can't find on internet "How to config the web server apache and change AcceptPathInfo to ON,

> 3. PHP 5.3.0 or above.
>
>    PHP is the interpreted language in which Horde Groupware is
>      written.
>
>    .. Note:: If possible, you should install PHP with your operating
>      system's
>               package manager. Alternatively you build PHP yourself.
>
>    To build PHP from sources, you can obtain it at
>
>    http:// www.php .net/
>
>    Follow the instructions in the PHP package to build PHP for your
>      one of the following    options::
>      system. If    you use Apache, be sure to build PHP as a library with
>
>    --with-apache
>         --with-apxs
>         --with-apxs2
>
> *etc, etc, etc more on the INSTALLATION link.*

Any idea on how to keep installing it? there is no resources on internet (videos, or tutorials) on how to install it in a different way or somethink, only for older versions like HORDE GROUPWARE 1.2 but this is really old software, what am trying to install is the 5.2

Comment: Before doing something this involved, step way back and learn the fundamentals. Along this way, you will learn about Ubuntu's package system and how to make use of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with SvW, especially because I don't think that the Horde install instructions are all that well laid out and certainly aren't very newb friendly. IMO this is not a good question for serverfault and would be much better in some sort of support forum (e.g. Ubuntu forums) where someone could hold your hand a bit and there could be more back and forth as you work bits out and have new problems...

IMO the instructions are tricky, mainly because:

- Confusing layout: e.g. 'Quick Install' instructions are noted as 1 but to me seem to be an abridged version of the rest of the instructions; 2. Is prerequisites so again, not really part of instructions (although very important...)
- Lack of consistency: e.g 1.1 recommends compiling PHP from source - but further down the page (2.3) it says min PHP is 5.3 and recommends using your OS package version...!?!

**But in the interest of trying to answer your question:**

Personally I would just follow the quick install instructions starting at step 3 (because you already have LAMP running).

To get it all working right though you will probably need to address at least some of the prerequisites too.

**Prerequisites [Horde install docs: 2. Prerequisites](http://www.horde.org/apps/groupware/docs/INSTALL#prerequisites)**
*Apache (2.2)*
I would check your Appache config file (IIRC /etc/apache2/apache2.conf) for

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

If it's not in there (or it's commented out) add it (on a new line - or uncomment it if it's commented out)

*PHP (2.3)*
Use the version you have installed already (I assume from package management) so just start at:

> The following PHP options are RECOMMENDED to enable advanced features
>   in Horde Groupware:

section 1 php setting will be in your php.ini file (IIRC `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`)

section 2 looks like you will need to configure your preferences, it's not that clear, but it seems to me that you will need to configure `<path-where-horde-installed>/config/prefs.php` (probably `/var/www/horde/config/prefs.php`). I'd recommend using MySQL (as you already have it installed - the 'M' in LAMP).

The other stuff in the prerequisites section will mostly be available as packages (e.g. IIRC GD support can be added by installing `php5-gd`). you may need to search Ubuntu packages to get the names right.

**Finally:**

TBH I don't think that serverfault is a great place to ask this question as I suspect that there will things that won;t work or new problems. The format here is more questions - > Answer, whereas I suspect you'll need more back and forth before you will get it sorted...

Comment: No, the way to go is to just install the stuff from the repos, because that will do all the hard work, including the configuration of PHP and Apache.

Comment: Here is what "saved me" I have HORDE operating and running!! bitnami.com/stack/horde/installer

Comment: @SvW I 100% agree when that's possible. But I'm pretty sure Horde [isn't available in the 14.04 repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=horde&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) (although it [is available for previous versions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=horde)). 
Also perhaps I wasn't clear enough (although I thought I was) I **was not** suggesting building/installing anything from source (except Horde itself); hence why I wrote the paragraph above "Finally:" (about searching Ubuntu packages).

Comment: It's in `universe`, named `php-horde-*`: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php-horde&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=universe

Comment: My apologies... Ok, weird... I wonder why it didn't come up as available for 14.04 when I searched for 'horde'...!?